# Como criar uma nova PostBox no WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Gostaria de saber se é possível, e como, criar uma tipo de **BoxPost** como a da imagem, só que dentro da **box**, em vez de categorias queria algo que pedisse.. "Titulo", "Ano", "Diretor", "Elenco", um `<select>`.. essas coisas.

E depois, caso seja possível, como buscar o valor de cada elemento no retorno com a publicação...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: da uma olhada ai parceiro veja se ajuda http://www.marcelotorresweb.com/usando-taxonomia-e-posts-personalizados-no-wordpress-3-0/

Comment: Talvez o que você queira é criar uma nova taxonomia personalizada e fazer com ela seja subordinada ao posts normais (em vez de subordinar a um CPT, *custom post type*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe "BoxPost" e provavelmente por isso que você não encontrou ainda como fazer, pois o nome correto disso é "Metabox".

Tem documentação completa sobre isso e em português em https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:add_meta_box

No caso é bem simples de ser feito, você vai ter o seu "Metabox" e dentro dele "Custom fields" (também fácil de encontrar com o nome de "Post meta").

Aqui um exemplo de como registrar seus "Metaboxes" e salvar seus "Custom fields":

```php
// Register metabox
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box' );

// Salvar custom fields
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );

/* Adiciona uma meta box na coluna principal das telas de edição de Post e Página */
function myplugin_add_custom_box() {
    $screens = array( 'post', 'page' );
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
        add_meta_box(
            'myplugin_sectionid',
            __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
            'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
            $screen
        );
    }
}

/* Imprime o conteúdo da meta box */
function myplugin_inner_custom_box( $post ) {

    // Faz a verificação através do nonce
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'myplugin_noncename' );

    // Os campos para inserção dos dados
    // Use get_post_meta para para recuperar um valor existente no banco de dados e usá-lo dentro do atributo HTML 'value' 
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );
    echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
       _e("Description for this field", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
}

/* Quando o post for salvo, salvamos também nossos dados personalizados */
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {

    // É necessário verificar se o usuário está autorizado a fazer isso
    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    // Agora, precisamos verificar se o usuário realmente quer trocar esse valor
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Por fim, salvamos o valor no banco

    // Recebe o ID do post
    $post_ID = $_POST['post_ID'];

    // Remove caracteres indesejados
    $mydata = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] );

    // Adicionamos ou atualizados o $mydata 
    update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_my_meta_value_key', $mydata );
}
```

Veja que o Custom field foi salvo em `update_post_meta($post_ID, '_my_meta_value_key', $mydata);` e com isso a chave do campo é `_my_meta_value_key`.

Sendo desta forma possível recuperar este valor dentro do loop de post utilizando `get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );`.

Você pode aprender mais sobre [Custom Fields na documentação oficial](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) também, mas em inglês.

Comment: Pelo que entendi nem é metabox e sim taxonomia

Comment: @Otto só ler: 'em vez de categorias queria algo que pedisse.. "Titulo", "Ano", "Diretor", "Elenco", um <select>.. essas coisas.". Então não parece ser uma taxonomia.

Comment: Realmente esta um pouco confuso o entendimento baseado na imagem ....

Comment: Dica: `add_action('save_post', 'funk', 10, 2); function funk($post_id, $post_object) {}`

Answer (score 0):

O segredo é colocar o parâmetro **side** na função `add_meta_box`

```
function custom_add_meta_boxes() {
    function custom_add_meta_box_teste() {
        ?>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore adipisci reprehenderit laborum quos cupiditate vitae? Voluptatum unde veniam optio dolores! Eos vel tenetur maiores placeat! Asperiores ipsum tempore ut in?</p>
        <?php
    }
    add_meta_box( 'teste', 'Teste', 'custom_add_meta_box_teste', null, 'side' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'custom_add_meta_boxes' );
```